# How to Export a Database query result to a CSV using Robot Framework?

Tags: python, database, oracle, robotframework, ride

For Data Validations on a database, i have to compare the data on the export of the spotfire report to data in the tables. So, i have taken the output of a query and inserted it into a variable on Ride. Next, i want to export this variable to a CSV file.
I installed CSVLibrary from 's4int' of 'robotframework-CSVLibrary' in github and it has a keyword named 'Append To Csv File'.

But when I am passing this output variable as an argument to the keyword, i am getting a common error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

How can i mitigate this? Can the query output be stored in bytes format?

[image: my worksheet]

Comment: Read the documentation https://rawgit.com/s4int/robotframework-CSVLibrary/master/doc/CSVLibrary.html#Append%20To%20Csv%20File The second argument `data` should be "iterable(e.g. list or tuple) data." You're passing there a string.

Comment: The 'query' keyword is returning the value as a list of tupples, is that not what we want here?

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshot.

Comment: Maybe you should use String Library's  `Encode String To Bytes` keyword